# Efficient way to keep a graph (2-D array)

Tags: graph, multidimensional-array, memory-efficient

Does anyone know a more efficient way  to keep a graph information (i.e. more efficient than keeping it as 2-D array), in terms of memory space or build time?

you can assume it's values are limited between 0-255.

Thanx!

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few standard ways to represent a (directed) graph:

For a graph of 4 nodes:

Adjacency matrix:

```
  0  1  2  3 
0 F  F  T  F
1 T  F  T  T
2 T  F  F  F
3 F  F  F  F
```

Edge List:

```
((0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0))
```

Adjacency list:

```
(
 (0, (2,)     ), 
 (1, (0, 2, 3)), 
 (2, (0,)     ),
 (4, (,)      ),
)
```

The Adjacency matrix is simple and the fastest representation, but takes the most memory (N*N, where N the number of rows), except if you have an extremely dense graph. You may be able to save some memory by using bit-arrays, if you only have a simple unweighted graph.

Edge List is simple, but slower than Adjacency Matrix, and is memory efficient if you have a sparse graph (2*M, where M is the number of edges).

Adjacency list is slightly more complicated (as you need variable-size array), but more memory efficient than Edge List if you have a large number of edges (2*N+M, where N is the number of vertices, M the number of edges)

The Adjacency Matrix takes (N*N*b) space. Edge List takes ((2+b)*N) memory. And adjacency list takes (2*N+M*(1+b)) memory.

If you know you always have less than 256 vertices (8-bit), and the weights are less than 256 (8-bit), then the Adjacency Matrix takes (N*N*8) space. Edge List takes (24*N) memory. And adjacency list takes (16*N+M*16) memory.

Comment: The last one is actually called an adjacency list.  Not sure what the second one is called.

Comment: The second one is called Edge List, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to modify your graph after creation, take a look at the compressed sparse row (CSR) format. A description from [BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph/doc/compressed_sparse_row.html):

> The CSR format stores vertices and
>   edges in separate arrays, with the
>   indices into these arrays
>   corresponding to the identifier for
>   the vertex or edge, respectively. The
>   edge array is sorted by the source of
>   each edge, but contains only the
>   targets for the edges. The vertex
>   array stores offsets into the edge
>   array, providing the offset of the
>   first edge outgoing from each vertex.
>   Iteration over the out-edges for the
>   ith vertex in the graph is achieved by
>   visiting edge_array[vertex_array[i]],
>   edge_array[vertex_array[i]+1], ...,
>   edge_array[vertex_array[i+1]]. This
>   format minimizes memory use to O(n +
>   m), where n and m are the number of
>   vertices and edges, respectively. The
>   constants multiplied by n and m are
>   based on the size of the integers
>   needed to represent indices into the
>   edge and vertex arrays, respectively(...)

[Here](https://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/online-study-material/topics/graphs-representation.php) is a good explanation of *Offset Arrays*:

> ```
>        Offset              Neighbours
>    1      1    -------------->  2
>    2      3    ------------     3
>    3      5    ----------  |->  1
>    4      9    --------  |      3
>    5     10    ------  | |--->  1
>    6     12    ----  | |        2
>    7     14    --  | | |        4
>                  | | | |        6
>                  | | |  ----->  3
>                  | |  ------->  6
>                  | |            7
>                  |  --------->  5
>                  |              7
>                   ----------->  5
>                                 6
> ```

### Efficient Insertion of Edges

Allowing to insert edges after creation can be achieved by essentially making the `Neighbours` array into a "linked-list". The offset points
into the first neighbour, and each neighbour contains a `Next` field. This points to the next edge.

From the same source:

> ```
>         Offset                 Node  Next
>    1      1    -------------->  2    2
>    2      3    ------------     3   -1
>    3      5    ----------  |->  1    4
>    4      9    --------  |      3   -1
>    5     10    ------  | |--->  1    6
>    6     12    ----  | |        2    7
>    7     14    --  | | |        4    8
>                  | | | |        6    9
>                  | | |  ----->  3   -1
>                  | |  ------->  6   11
>                  | |            7   -1
>                  |  --------->  5   13
>                  |              7   -1
>                   ----------->  5   15
>                                 6   -1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is fairly sparse then you'll save space by storing it as an edge list (from node, to node) rather than an adjacency matrix.  If all edges are bidirectional then you only need store any edge once, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a list of graph representations I found useful here:

[Graph Data Structures](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/graph-data-structures.html)